# twitteR lookupUsers for loop

Tags: r, twitter

I'm relatively new to both R and twitteR and am attempting to write some code that will allow me to export a data frame showing multiple Twitter User Names, the number of friends for each, the number of followers for each, the number of times they are listed in public lists, and the number of time they have been mentioned, hopefully making it look like below:

**User** | **Date** | **Friends** | **Followers** | **Listed** | **Mentions** | **StatusCount**

The closest reference I could find on SO is [this question, which is on "Hold"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320706/using-twitter-package-how-to-solve-twinterfaceobjdoapicallcmd-params-method), and when I try running the code listed, it gives the following error:

```
"Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 
  'by' must specify one or more columns as numbers, names or logical"
```

**Code:**

```
library(RCurl)
library(bitops)
library(digest)
library(ROAuth)
library(rjson)
library(twitteR)
options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))

load("twitteR_credentials")
registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)

clients <- lookupUsers(c('Name','Name1','Name2'), cainfo = "cacert.pem")

for(i in 1:length(clients)) {
   start <- getUser(clients[i])
   friends.object <- start$friendsCount
   followers.object <- start$followersCount
   status.object <- start$statusesCount
   listed.object <- start$listedCount
   mentions.object <- start$mentions
   data <- merge(data.frame(User=start$id, Friends=friends.object), 
                 data.frame(User=start$id, Followers=followers.object), 
                 data.frame(User=start$id, Statuses=status.object), 
                 data.frame(User=start$id, Listed=listed.object)
                 data.frame(User=start$id, Mentions=mentions.object), all=T)
   filename <- paste(clients[i],"Twiter Data.csv", sep=' ')
   setwd("filepath")
   write.csv(data, file=filename)
   remove(data)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't want to setup everything that is necessary call the twitter API, but I think the issue is that you're attempting to merge multiple data frames at once but the `merge()` function can only handle two at a time. Try this instead: `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by="id"), list(<all of your data frames to merge>))`

Comment: Thank you for that @David; after adding that in, I get the following error:

`Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot coerce class "structure("user", package = "twitteR")" to a data.frame`